# Export/import in client JavaScript without build system

Tags: javascript, babeljs

In ES6 added new feature - using construction export and import. Example:

```
import name from "module-name";
export let name = 'test'
```

But browsers not supported this. If connected Babel, this feature will not work. Manuals recommended use Build system. How use this features in browser without build system? Babel, Babel + RequireJS do not give result.

Comment: You might be able to find a polyfill library to cover these functions. The polyfill is just a JavaScript file that checks if the browser has the required capability and, if it hasn't, then plugs the necessary code in. The only thing with polyfills is they run a bit slower that the inbuilt functions.

Comment: Babel just transpiles the ES6 to ES5 common JS. For it to work in a browser you have to use something like Browserify. But: build system. You might try something like [http://jspm.io/](http://jspm.io/) which uses either Babel or Traceur silently (I've found) in the background.

Comment: Something somewhere has to built it. What is your definition of build system? What is your goal with avoiding a pre-deploy build system. Transpiling in the browser is slow once you get many files and not recommended for serious use.